# one to one annotation hibernate, can't update values

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 2 tables created in hibernate, that do not update values correctly. So every time I run the code, it inserts voter, and when I add vote it updates sin number in the Votes table but doesn't insert party choice 
[image]

[image]

I stuck on this problem and not sure how to update values properly so that whenever voter registered it add it to the table, and then I check when sin exist then => vote => add party choice and who voted(sin number)

Here is my addVotes and addVoter methods where I should set all this parameters into a table

```
public void addVoter(Voter voter) { 
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(voter);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();    
    }


public void addVote(Votes votes, int sin) { 
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Voter voter = (Voter)session.get(Voter.class, sin);

    voter.setVotes(votes);
    votes.setVoter(voter);

    session.save(votes);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

servet:

```
int sinNumber =  Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sinNumber"));

            voteMessage = "User with SIN: " + sinNumber + " already registered. Please vote";
            request.setAttribute("voteMessage", voteMessage);

                        response.sendRedirect("voteParty.jsp");

            String party = request.getParameter("party");

            votes.setParty(party);

            dao.addVote(votes, sinNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not work like that. one of them should be first persistent then call the save for the second alone